# ./src/main.js in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client but I do not have main.js. I want to use typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am making a demo Vue.js 3 app with tailwind and typescript. Whenever I run the app I get an error reading:

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./src/main.js in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?https://192.168.2.102:8090&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './styles/app.css';

createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .mount('#app');
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="justify-center flex bg-yellow-300 items-center h-screen">
        <div class="text-4xl">
            {{ hello }} 
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Vue} from "vue-property-decorator";

export default class App extends Vue {

    hello = 'Hello world'

}
</script>
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '^/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8081'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8090 --https true",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12"
  },
```

has anyone else had this issue too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Behind the scenes, `@vue/cli` uses webpack. Webpacks' config is accessible through `vue.config.js` and, technically, you could manually update the app's entry point. [Docs here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#working-with-webpack).

However, the recommended way to add typescript to an existing `@vue/cli` project is to add the [dedicated plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-typescript) by running

```
vue add typescript
```

in the root of your project.

You're supposed to do this without manually changing your files from `.js` to `.ts`, the script will do it for you. Most importantly, it will make the necessary webpack config changes, one of them being changing the entry point from `src/main.js` to `src/main.ts`.

Comment: If you  manually installed TypeScript into an existing Vue project and get `This relative module was not found: ./src/main.ts`, you have to manually rename `src/main.js` to `src/main.ts`.